# How to deal with an $xy\le 1$ constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints, convex-geometry

I have to solve the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{align*}
\min_{x,y} &\{-x-y\} \\
\text{such that} \\
y &\ge 3 \\
y &\le 30 \\
x &\ge 0 \\
xy &\le 1 \\
\end{align*}
$$
I want to use a second order cone programming (SOCP) solver because the rest of my problem (not shown here) can be formulated as a second order cone program. However, my problem is the $xy\le 1$ hyperbolic constraint that has the inequality "the wrong way" to be written as a second order cone. It would be great if you could show me for this toy problem how one might deal with the $xy\le 1$ constraint. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $0\le x\le\frac{1}{y}$ and $y\ge 3$ imply $0\le x\le\frac{1}{3}$. So we clearly minimise by taking $y=30,x=\frac{1}{30}$.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is how to reformulate it for a computer convex solver to solve, not by hand. This is an example problem of a much more complicated problem that I'm dealing with.

Comment: I would say that it is not possible to formulate your problem as a convex optimization problem.

Comment: @gerw is correct. It's not convex.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I've not gone over the theory of convex optimization. Is it generally true that if a constraint is non-convex, then it is impossible to make it convex? Perhaps there are techniques to convexify this constraint?

Comment: No. With very few exceptions, you can't take a non-convex constraint and make it convex. You must apply nonconvex techniques here.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint $xy\le1$ is non-convex, so the problem cannot be solved as stated using SOCP techniques.